# wget download one mp3 but not the other (http vs. https)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to download audio mp3 files with wget. It is strange that it works with one URL but not the other. While url1 is fine, url2 gave me 'HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found' message. Both links work fine in chrome. The only difference between them is HTTP vs HTTPS. I put the error messages below. What could be the problem? Any ideas? Many thanks!

```
import wget
url1 = 'http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3'
url2 = 'https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-PY0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Module%205/data/PolynomialRegressionandPipelines.mp3'

filename = wget.download(url1)
filename = wget.download(url2)

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-52669abd6e75> in <module>
      1 import wget
      2 url = 'https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-PY0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Module%205/data/PolynomialRegressionandPipelines.mp3'
----> 3 filename = wget.download(url)
      4 filename

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wget.py in download(url, out, bar)
    524     else:
    525         binurl = URL
--> 526     (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
    527     filename = detect_filename(url, out, headers)
    528     if outdir:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    245     url_type, path = _splittype(URL)
    246 
--> 247     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    248         headers = fp.info()
    249 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532
    533         return response

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
        647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
        648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
    --> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
        650 
        651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

    HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: url2 has a extra space after `cloud-object-`

Comment: I revised and tested it again. It is still not working. The extra space was a mistake made when I pasted the code to stackoverflow.

Comment: If you're using a Linux environment you can simply use the os module instead of wget module. First, check the path to your wget executable by  `which wget`. For me it was located at `/usr/bin/wget`. Then you can use `os.system('/usr/bin/wget "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-PY0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Module%205/data/PolynomialRegressionandPipelines.mp3"')` to download your file.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this does not answer the `wget` issue but as a workaround
if you can use `requests` module it works fine with both.

```
import requests

url1 = 'http://www.futurecrew.com/skaven/song_files/mp3/razorback.mp3'
url2 = 'https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-PY0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Module%205/data/PolynomialRegressionandPipelines.mp3'

first_url_to_get = requests.get(url1)

with open('razorback.mp3', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(first_url_to_get.content)


second_url_to_get = requests.get(url2)

with open('PolynomialRegressionandPipelines.mp3', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(second_url_to_get.content)
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was able to solve the issue with urllib.request. I was just trying to figure out why wget works with one url but not the other. 
`import urllib.request  
url='https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-PY0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Module%205/data/PolynomialRegressionandPipelines.mp3' 
filename = 'PolynomialRegressionandPipelines.mp3' 
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)`